# mutate several features simultaniously with a custom function

Tags: r, dplyr

I've found several SO posts on this already but cannot see how to apply to my specific problem.

I have a dataframe with a number of features that I would like to simultaneously mutate. I want to write over them rather than create new features.

E.g. using mtcars. Suppose I want to amend am, gear and carb to be 1 if greater than 0 and 0 otherwise. For each of those 3 features. How could I do that?

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(vs:carb, funs(???))
```

I want to apply a custom function of this form `ifelse(x > 0, 1, 0)` where x is either of the 3 features being worked on.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(vs:carb), funs(ifelse(. > 0, 1, 0)))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `vars()` for `vs:carb` to parse, and you use `.` as a stand-in for the argument in `funs`:

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(vs:carb), funs(ifelse(. > 0, 1, 0)))
#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    1    1
# 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    1    1
# 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    1    1
# 4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    1    1
# 5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    1    1
# 6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    1    1
# ...
```

This is explained in the `?funs` help page:

> A list of functions specified by:
>
> - Their name, `"mean"`
> - The function itself, `mean`
> - A call to the function with `.` as a dummy argument, `mean(., na.rm = TRUE)`

With this corresponding to the third bullet.